# combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have two columns in my dataframe as `start_time` and `finish_time` in my dataset, i have to find the time between them and add a new column to dataframe as `time_between`. Actually I want that `time_between` as minutes. I tried the code but I got the error which is on title.

```
datetime.combine(date.today(), df["finish_time"]) - datetime.combine(date.today(), df["start_time"])


    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-052753af9b58> in <module>
      1 from datetime import datetime, date
      2 
----> 3 datetime.combine(date.today(), df["finish_time"]) - datetime.combine(date.today(), df["start_time"])

TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not Series
```

I'am sharing the project repository so you can see the all the code and my excelsheet:

https://github.com/baranacikgoz/Reading-Habits-Data-Science-Project

Comment: Does df['time_between'] = df["finish_time"] - df["start_time"] work for you? If not, why?

Comment: No mate doesnt. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```py
    def time_between(df):
       return datetime.combine(date.today(), df["finish_time"]) - datetime.combine(date.today(), df["start_time"])

    df['time_between'] = df.apply(time_between, axis=1)
```

You have to apply your code to the dataframe, because pandas does not support subtraction of `datetime.time` objects.

Comment: it worked thanks very much, but it shows as day, so all the values are 0 days, how can i change them to minutes ?

Comment: sorry mate your code completely functional, i had missed somewhere before comment this thanks again